# Elasticsearch - How to find exact value in a long text using query string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having troubles using the Elasticsearch technology. I would like to find an exact value in a long text using the query string.

Example:
If I am looking for the terms "like my dogs", I would like the document containing "I like my dogs and cats" to be retrieved.

To do so, I want to use the query string with the quotes (as I had to implement the logical operators AND OR NOT):

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "like my dogs"
    }
}
```

I probably have a bad mapping. Here is the mapping for the field to query:

```
"settings":{
     "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
             "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "french_stemmer", "elision", "french_stop"]
        },
        "lowercase": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
},
"mappings": {
    "content": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
              "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
               "custom":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "lowercase" }
         }
    }
}
```

The problem with this mapping is that Elasticsearch also retrieves documents having the following text in content : "my dog is beautiful" because it matches the "my dog" (tokenization included).

How can I overcome this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you make your field 'not_analyzed', Elasticsearch will return the exact results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ElasticSearch used the **standard** analyzer. With this analyzer stop words are not searchable.

With the **not_analyzed** param, you cannot retrieve you content into a sentence like you want.

With the lowercase analyzer you set the keyword tokenizer, so the field is identify as steam so no searchable as you want.

Please modify the lowercase analyzer with a whitespace tokenizer.

Should be solve your issue.

BR

NicolasY